# Jquery plugin instances issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So this is most likely a very simple problem which i just can't figure out.

Basically i want to select multiple elements and create new instance for each object.

Then later on i want to be able call `public` methods from outside plugin.

Now the problem is that when i call those methods i can't seem to access each instance `settings`, well i can, but it looks like those settings are overridden when looping trough elements.

I think i won't post code here since it's quite long, but i have made this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5EGEY/), and i have explained what doesn't work in the comments.

Just to be clear, plugin is called `two` times, then i call public method called `test` which should set this text `container` to `.result` div but it sets `container2` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to attach data to dom element inside `init`

   $.data(obj, "settings", settings);
2. You better call method in context of dom element

   methods[method].apply(this, options);

http://jsfiddle.net/5EGEY/1/

Comment: I'm not sure if i got `apply` part since i don't need to pass anything to `test` method could you perhaps explain it a little bit more?

Comment: It's common practice to have `this` pointing to dom element inside plugin method. Though its not necessary. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring